# mktime having problems with certain years?

Tags: c, mktime

I am having a problem with years in `mktime()`.

Every time I pass a year lower than 1970 into my `struct tm` and then run the `mktime()` function to convert my structure, it fails (returns -1).

Does anyone have any idea why and if I can make this work somehow?

Comment: How can we know something which we cannot see ? Post your code.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: The code is nothing more than the standard tm structure and I am using Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is never going to work, since it's by definition outside [the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is the start for Unix time. [The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) states:

> The `ctime()`, `gmtime()` and `localtime()` functions all take an argument of data type time_t which represents calendar time. When interpreted as an absolute time value, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

If it fails to convert the input into Unix time, it's documented to return `-1` so that's why you're seeing that result.

Comment: Thanks guys, so there is no way around this even on Windows?

Comment: Not aware of one, no. There is the concept of a negative value expressing times before the epoch, but that's not supported by `mktime()`.

Comment: I see, so I would have to use a completely different approach that would not allow me to use the mktime function if I wanted to get the years before 1970 working?

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior.  Per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html):

> ```
>    If the specified broken-down time cannot be represented as calendar
>    time (seconds since the Epoch), mktime() returns (time_t) -1 and does
>    not alter the members of the broken-down time structure.
> ```